# Qt5. fstream was not declared in the scope

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, fstream

Нужен fstream, чтобы считать с файла данные как

```
#include <fstream>
...
fstream f("users.txt");
while(f)
{
    f>>value1>>value2>>value3;
}
```

Написал код, запускаю программу, пишет ошибку

```
C:\Users\david\Documents\Carsharring_files\mainwindow.cpp:47: ошибка: 'fstream' was not declared in this scope
     fstream f("users.txt");
     ^
```

Использую QT 5.1. Сразу же и отвечу почему не использую QFile, в документации я не смог найти считывание данных так, как мне нужно. Там только через getline()

Comment: `std::fstream`?

Comment: Хах, заработало) про std забыл